# add 5 columns table row layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have application in the android. The interfaces depend on `tablelayout`, each row in which the content differs from the other.
I want to show 5 columns in some rows ... how can that be?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable number of columns in each row, here's an example:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- First row has 5 columns -->
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Column 1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:text="Column 2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:text="Column 3"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:text="Column 4"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:text="Column 5" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- Second row has 3 columns -->
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Column 1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:text="Column 2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:text="Column 3"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: You can put any view inside the tablerow

`<TableRow>
            <Button
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Column 1" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>`